# Call an Ace custom autocompleter on every keystroke

Tags: ace-editor, react-ace

I'm adding a custom auto-completer to Ace. I have it working just fine *as such*, except my custom auto-completer is only called every few keypresses, which doesn't really work in practice.

For example, if I type "W", my auto-completer is returning `["W", "Waiter", "Wales"]`. I then type "Wi" and my auto-completer code is *not* called again. The above list is filtered by Ace to display just "Waiter" as an option, highlighting the first and third characters. But I want it to call my completer so I can call the backend and get a new list of options based on the "Wi" prefix. Eventually, this happens on the fourth keypress. Once I type "Will", my function is called again, I return new options, and the option list shown to the user is updated.

I can't work out the behaviour. If I type "University", my auto-completer is only called on "U" and "Unive" -- so five characters needed this time rather than four. Why is this?!

I'd like Ace to call my function on every keypress. Is this possible?!

I'm actually using Ace via `react-ace`:

```
  <AceEditor
    mode="java"
    theme="github"
    onChange={(value) => setText(value)}
    enableLiveAutocompletion={true}
  />
```

My auto-complete function:

```
import * as ace from "ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace";
const langTools = ace.acequire("ace/ext/language_tools");

const myCompleter = {
  getCompletions: function (editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
    if (prefix.length === 0) {
      callback(null, []);
      return;
    }

    backend.autocomplete(prefix).then((options) => {
      callback(
          null,
          options.map((option, index) => {
            return {
              caption: option,
              value: option,
            };
          })
      );
    });
  },
};

langTools.setCompleters([myCompleter]);
```

## Edit

I've done some looking through the source code and I think I understand now why it's an "arbitrary" number of keypresses before my code is called again.

I think the design of the autocompleter in Ace is that the completion provider should provide *all* possible autocompletions. Ace will then filter that list as the user types. When there are *no* filtered options left, `Autocomplete.prototype.detach` is called, which makes the completer inactive. The user sees no autocompletions at this point. On the next keypress, `Autocomplete.prototype.updateCompletions` is called, and, because the completer is inactive, my completion provider code is called again, populating a new list of options. The process then repeats.

If I ensure the `keepPopupPosition` parameter to `Autocomplete.prototype.updateCompletions` is always `false`, everythign works as I want it to. If I've understood the code correctly, my use case is just not how Ace is supposed to work. Looks like raising a PR to add my use case is the only option here, but let me know if I've misunderstood something!